# Need more css class in jquery split

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need help with something about jquery split.

You can see the following code have:

```
if (KEY == '1') {
      var sid = ID.split("likes");
    } else {
      var sid = ID.split("like");
    }
```

I want to add also other css class in split like the following code **(I need help here)**:

```
if (KEY == '1') {
      var sid = ID.split("likes", "happy",...);
    } else {
      var sid = ID.split("like", "unhappy",...);
    }
```

My full code is this:

```
      var count= 0;
      $('body').on("click",'.do', function() {
        var count = 0;
        var KEY = parseInt($(this).attr("data"));
        var ID = $(this).attr("id");
        if (KEY == '1') {
          var sid = ID.split("likes");
        } else {
          var sid = ID.split("like");
        }
        var New_ID = sid[1];
        var REL = $(this).attr("rel");
        var URL = $.base_url + 'do_post.php';
        var dataString = 'msg_id=' + New_ID + '&rel=' + REL;
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: URL,
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          success: function(html) {
            if (html) {
              if (REL == 'Like') {
                 // Do Something for 
                 // var sid = ID.split("likes");
$("#likes" + New_ID).prepend("<span id='you" + New_ID + "'><div class='icon-newL icon-like-new'></div></span>");
              } else if(REL == 'UnLike'){
                count--;  
                // Do something for
                // var sid = ID.split("like");
               //$("#likess" + New_ID).hide('slow');
              }
              if(REL == 'Happy'){
                 $("#happy" + New_ID).prepend("<span id='you" + New_ID + "'><div class='icon-newL icon-happy-new'></div></span>");
              } else if (REL == 'UnHappy'){
               //$("#unhappy" + New_ID).hide('slow');
               }
            }

          }
        });

        return false;
      });
```

html

```
<div class="do" rel="Like" id="like5">Like</div>
<div class="do" rel="Happy" id="happy5">Happy</div>
```

Anyone can help me in this regard ?

Comment: What is the value of `ID`? Add an example input and expected result

Comment: @Tushar that is post id like 1,2,3,4,5,

Comment: why are you comparing number to string? Really not clear what issue is here

Comment: Add all possible values and all expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the JavaScript "split" function, you can pass in a RegExp in order to split on multiple values. You could do something like:

```
ID.split(/likes|happy/)
```

This will split on EITHER. You can add more, separated by a | character.

Comment: That'll not match _like_, use `/likes?|happy/`

Comment: @Tushar so if i add some other values then i need to do it like this `/likes?|happy?/haha?/.../`    ?

Comment: @innovation No, `?` will make the previous character match zero or once. As you want to match `like` and `likes` by making `s?` will match both.